# IDEA Plugin: PersistentStateComponent not persisting xml

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I can not get my plugin to persist its state. 
The file configProvider.xml never gets created, nor does the `@State` annotation has any effect (apparently).

This is the relevant part in the plugin.xml

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <applicationService serviceImplementation="my.plugins.idea.vcs.ConfigProvider" serviceInterface="my.plugins.idea.vcs.ConfigProvider"/>
</extensions>
```

This is the Class providing the object that should get persisted:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.components.PersistentStateComponent;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.State;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

@State(
  name = "ConfigProvider",
  storages = {
@Storage(id = "main", file = "$APP_CONFIG$/configProvider.xml") 
  }
)
public class ConfigProvider  implements PersistentStateComponent<ConfigProvider.State> {

  private State state = new State();

  class State {
    public State() {}
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> commitTypes = null;
    public Integer selectedDefaultCommitTypeIndex = null;
    public String jiraApiUrl;
    public String jiraAuthorization;
    public String jiraFilterId;
  } 

  public static ConfigProvider getInstance() {
return ServiceManager.getService(ConfigProvider.class);
  }

  @Override
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
  public ConfigProvider.State getState() {
return state; // gets called regulary
  } 

  @Override
  public void loadState(ConfigProvider.State state) {
this.state = state; // not called at all
  }

}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Christopher

Comment: How did this work out for you? Did you try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help, making the `State` class public and static?

```
public static class State {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I can not exatcly reproduce if your change finally made it running, but it is working now. Since I refactored a couple of things this may not have been the only thing I had to change. But I accepted your answer, and attached the working example as a new answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great, hopefully it will help someone else out there in future. :)

Comment: Yes, especially because it is not very easy to find example-implementations besides the official ones.

Answer (score 5):

This is now a working example:

```
package com.foo

import com.intellij.openapi.components.ApplicationComponent;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.PersistentStateComponent;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.State;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@State(
  name = "ConfigProviderState",
  storages = {
    @Storage(id = "other", file = "$APP_CONFIG$/configProvider.xml")
  }
)
public class ConfigProvider implements ApplicationComponent, PersistentStateComponent<ConfigProvider.State> {

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public String getComponentName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
  @Override
  public void disposeComponent() {}
  @Override
  public void initComponent() {}

  public State state = new State();

  public static class State {
    public State() {}
    public String foo;
  }

  @Override
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
  public ConfigProvider.State getState() {
    return state; //Saves all public variables to disk.
  }

  @Override
  public void loadState(ConfigProvider.State state) {
    this.state = state; //restores state from disk
  }


  public String getFoo() {
    if (this.state.foo == null) {
      this.state.foo = "https://jira.rz.is/rest/api/2/";
    }
    return this.state.foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.state.foo = foo;
  }

}
```

plugin.xml

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    <applicationService
      serviceImplementation="com.foo.ConfigProvider"
      serviceInterface="com.foo.ConfigProvider"
      overrides="true"
      />
  </extensions>

  <application-components>
    <component>
      <implementation-class>com.foo.ConfigProvider</implementation-class>
      <interface-class>com.foo.ConfigProvider</interface-class>
    </component>
  </application-components>

  <project-components>
    <!-- Add your project components here -->
  </project-components
```

Answer (score 4):

There is essential note on the page [Persisting State of Components](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/persisting_state_of_components.html) :

> Note that instances of extensions cannot persist their state by implementing `PersistentStateComponent`

Therefore, your first attempt did not work out due to component was enlisted as part of the `<extensions>`.
The second version works because the component is now registered inside   `<application-components>`
May it's worth to remove the `extension` section to make the answer more precise.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If your extension needs to have persistent state, then you need to define a separate service responsible for managing that state.

Comment: this didn't work for me FWIW...adding it to app components didn't work